# Javascript unexpected { token error

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webrtc

I'm trying to make a WebRTC demo but I'm getting following error

`Unexptected token {`

the screen shot is attached. Please help to solve this error.

[image]

Comment: I've downloaded example from this link http://www.webrtc.org/running-the-demos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{content }` here content must be in key value format in JavaScript.
 Problem is you trying to create a variable with invalid syntax.

```
var inittiator = {{inittiator }};
```

must be like

```
 var inittiator = { key:{internalkey:value}};// depth 2
 var inittiator = { key: value};// depth 1
```

Comment: but when I try by removing extra `{}` set then the same-like error is coming `Unexptected token }`

Comment: I added code in answer you have to follow key : value format for {}.

Comment: Yes.. its solved thanks, however it just need minor modification afterwards.. but its solved